# PySpark: Generating a Unique IDs for Data with Non-uniform and Repeated IDs

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataset that is as indicated below. The first column is a date column, the second column comprises an id that can apply to any user (within the same department) and a given user can have multiple of these ids. The 3rd column is specific to a particular user but every so often, this id can be changed in case a user forgets it. The last column comprises of names and individuals can have similar names. I want to harmonize columns 1 and 2 prior to analysis as indicated below.

Input Dataset

| Date | Id2 | id3 | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | 001 | AA | Name1 |
| 2018-01-02 | 001 | AB | Name1 |
| 2018-01-01 | 001 | AC | Name1 |
| 2018-01-04 | 003 | AA | Name1 |
| 2018-01-01 | 004 | AA | Name1 |
| 2018-01-01 | 001 | AD | Name2 |
| 2018-01-04 | 002 | AE | Name3 |
| 2018-01-04 | 005 | AG | Name1 |

Desired output:

| Date | Id2 | id3 | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | 001 | AA | Name1 |
| 2018-01-02 | 001 | AA | Name1 |
| 2018-01-01 | 001 | AA | Name1 |
| 2018-01-04 | 001 | AA | Name1 |
| 2018-01-01 | 001 | AA | Name1 |
| 2018-01-01 | 001 | AD | Name2 |
| 2018-01-04 | 002 | AE | Name3 |
| 2018-01-04 | 005 | AG | Name1 |

Answer (score 1):

so we have a table below and you are trying to map id2 column to just one id3 column because you said that they can be mapped to multiple ids, this would be my approach.

```
+---+----
|id2|id3|
+---+----
|001| AA| 
|001| AC| 
|003| BB|
|003| DE| 
+---+---
```

First i would create a flag column that flags 1 ID2 column that has multiple ID3 with this code.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

flag_df = dataframe.withColumn(
"dedup_flag",
F.dense_rank().over(
    Window.partitionBy(
        'id2'
    ).orderBy(F.col('id3').desc())) # this would help you pick the highest or lowest value in id3
 )
```

which results in

```
+---+----+-----------+
|id2|id3|dedup_flag  |
+---+----+-----------+
|001| AA|           1|
|001| AC|           2|
|003| BB|           1|
|003| DE|           2|
+---+----+-----------+
```

Then all you need to do is filter where dedup_flag = 1 and just do a left join with your original dataframe and flag dataframe on id2 to pull in all id3's associated to a given id2 with this code below.

```
final_df = dataframe.drop('id3').join(
flag_df.filter(F.col('dedup_flag') == 1).select('id2','id3'),
on= 'id2',
how= 'left'
)
```

which results to

```
+---+----
|id2|id3|
+---+----
|001| AA| 
|001| AA| 
|003| BB|
|003| BB| 
+---+---
```

I hope this helped, acknowledge if this worked for you :) -Paula

Comment: Thanks for the help Paula. Concerning the output, I would like to generate a time series output as indicated above. Let me explain this further: Id2 is a department code like sales logistics etc. Given that these departments are in different locations, the codes were different but want to harmonize that. id3 points to an individual but can be reassigned within the same department. The last column contains names of the individuals. What I seek in a output as indicated above that harmonizes all id3s that are tied to a particular department whose id has also been reduced to a single id.

Answer (score 0):

before I can help I need to understand the question, so for each unique ID in column 2 generate a unique ID column?

Comment: Basically, the ID in column 2 can be shared by one or more individuals but if an individual has more than 2 of these IDs, what I seek is to collapse it into 1. For example, if column 2 comprised telephone numbers and an individual can have multiple telephone numbers, what I would like is to have only 1 telephone number that can be used to identify that individual and of it were a department that has 2 or more mobile lines, then just have one telephone number for that particular department

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).